# MongoDB C# Driver MongoCursorNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mongodb

I’m currently using C# driver (v2.17.1 ) to connect to local Mongo Database and then loop through every document and update a field inside the document.
One iteration might take 2 to 5 seconds .

This works up until 1.4k to 1.5k documents .
Later there is an exception which is like below :

MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorNotFoundException: Cursor 4299221987179083891 not found on server localhost:27017 using connection 1465.
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AsyncCursor1.ExecuteGetMoreCommand(IChannelHandle channel, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AsyncCursor1.GetNextBatch(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AsyncCursor1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AsyncCursorEnumerator1.MoveNext()

My C# code looks like below :

```
string connectionString = @“mongodb://localhost:27017/”;
MongoClient dbClient = new MongoClient(connectionString );
string dbName = “mongodbname”;
string collectionName = “mongodbcollectionname”;
var db_sample = dbClient.GetDatabase(dbName);
var collection = db_sample.GetCollection(collectionName);

foreach (DataModel cdm in collection.AsQueryable())
{
//Iteration and updation of documents .
}
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what time does it take before error?

Comment: the same time which it took for other documents i.e,  2 to 5 seconds (since there is an API call being made)

Comment: I mean the time between when you've started iterating and when error happened

Comment: I assume something close to 10 mins?

Comment: No, its close to 40 to 50 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

The server has timeout value `cursorTimeoutMillis` for cursor. You can read about it [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.cursorTimeoutMillis). The doc says that by default it should be a 10 mins + time before next `getMore` will happen (when you're iterating data on the client, most of the time you use a batch data and only when the batch is ended you call `getMore` to get a new batch). It's a bit suspicious that it takes 40-50 mins in your case, but try to set this value let's say to 2hours and see what will happen. Here you can see how to set [it](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/setParameter/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.setParameter). With c# driver you can do something like this:

```
var db = client.GetDatabase("admin");
db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{ setParameter: 1, cursorTimeoutMillis: #big value# }")
```

However, I would not recommend using so long living cursor, if something happens with a server during this long operation, a new server election that will happen on the server side won't affect your cursor, ie cursor always communicates with the initial server which may down at some point.

Comment: Let me check this as well. 
However my doubt still persists . 
How is the cursor relatable to AsQueryable()  since i'm not even using the cursor explicitly?

Comment: you use it behind the scene, you may see it in your exception